# How to retrieve stripe session id php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I hate to ask such a simple question on here but I can't seem to figure this out. I create a stripe checkout session that goes through successfully, but am having trouble getting a response. I have read through stripe docs and answers on here, but still cannot seem to get the stripe session id returned. Here's what I have tried

```
<?php

require_once('stripe-php-7.86.0/init.php');

$priceId = $_POST['priceId'];

$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
    'my secret key here'
  );

  $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'success_url' => 'http://localhost/stripe_test/success.html',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/stripe_test/cancel.html',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [
      [
        'price' => $priceId,
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
    ],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
  ]);

  // I've tried all of these individually, none of them work.
  
  echo json_encode($stripe);
  echo $stripe['id'];
  echo json_encode($stripe['id']);
  echo $stripe->checkout->sessions['id'];
  echo json_encode(['sessionId' => $stripe['id']]);
```

Comment: Hey I'm doing this storing it in $_SESSION['checkout_id'] and checking it on return to the success page and it's not always matching in production, is this how you'd recommend storing the checkout ID between checkout and success? appologies as i see this is an older thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the [official Stripe documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create), you can to assign the returned value of `$stripe->checkout->sessions->create` to the variable you want to use, then access the property `id`.

`$stripe->checkout->sessions->create` returns the `Session object`

For example

```
$stripe_session = $stripe->checkout->sessions->create([
    'success_url' => 'http://localhost/stripe_test/success.html',
    'cancel_url' => 'http://localhost/stripe_test/cancel.html',
    'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
    'line_items' => [
      [
        'price' => $priceId,
        'quantity' => 1,
      ],
    ],
    'mode' => 'subscription',
  ]);
echo $stripe_session->id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think response->id will be you session id
[image]